# Individual "Created By" User is not Receiving Workflow Email in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, sharepoint-email

I have an individual user that is not receiving emails when my 2013 SharePoint workflow runs (the workflow is written so that it sends to the "Created By" user). All other individuals are not experiencing issues. I have checked the information in UPSA, and all information is correctly pulling from AD (including the correct email). I have even forced a Full Sync, with no solution.

Has anybody else experienced this issue?

Comment: Can you determine if the email is being sent?  Not receiving an email is not the same as the email not being sent.  As mentioned in Johan's answer, a message trace can help with that.  I think SharePoint's send email action will cause the workflow to error out if it is unable to send the email.  Does the workflow finish successfully?

Comment: I had my email admin check the individual's inbox and she can see that my SP server is communicating with the email server, but the message never makes it through. I should also mention that we have SP on premise and not O365 (can a message trace still be run in this instance?). No other users are experiencing the issue, and the workflow is completing successfully.

Comment: Seeing your comment on Johan's answer below, I don't know a thing about Lotus Notes (other than I hate it), so I couldn't tell you if it's possible.

Comment: Haha if I could love your comment I would. You are definitely not alone!

Answer (score 0):

Could run a message trace on that user to see if any emails have come in from no-reply@sharepointonline.com?

This might help you figure out if the workflow is even sending them.

You might also get away with using 'Modified By' if the workflow runs on item creation.

Comment: Our corporation uses SP on premise and not O365. Am I still able to run a message trace?

Comment: Yes, you can still run one. The message trace would be run from your Exchange admin panel. Assuming you are using MS Exchange server or O365 to handle your emails.

Comment: We are not using either as we have Lotus Notes.

Answer (score 0):

Is there an off change that the 'created by' user is getting their permissions through an AD group? Those people don't 'exist' as people in a SP2013 workflow - the workflow manager doesn't dig into the AD groups to authenticate. The same reason you can't send to any type of string email address that isn't tied to a person.
If that's true, a long shot I know but thought I'd mention it, then change the workflow to a 2010 version and it will work.

Comment: I had my team check the AD side and the individual has no specific permissions on that end, so unfortunately not.